# A lot of system settings are missing after installing Pantheon

Tags: pantheon

I installed pantheon on Ubuntu 13.10 and a ton of settings are missing. I only have these settings: defaults, desktop, tweaks (I installed tweaks), keyboard, power, and about. What do I do?

Answer (score 4):

This is likely caused by the setting of `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`.

What does `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` say in a terminal?

The .desktop files used for gnome-control-center components contain a line like `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;` and are therefore not displayed with another `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` setting.

Try `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center` from a terminal.

I am not sure, where and if it makes sense to override this variable, but I have just done so in my custom startup script for AwesomeWM.

Comment: I don't use pantheon any more so i can't mark this as correct because I can't test it. If someone can say that this is correct I can mark this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't Pantheon-specific. This happens with every desktop that isn't GNOME or Unity: `i3`, `xfce`, and `awesome`, to name a few for Googlebot's benefit.

Blueeyed gave the correct answer, but is also right that it's not obvious where to override that variable. Here's my solution: create a wrapper for `gnome-control-center` so that it is the only program affected.

## Steps

1. Create a new shell script in ~/bin/gnome-control-center by cutting and pasting the following commands in the terminal:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/bin
   cd ~/bin
   echo 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME exec /usr/bin/gnome-control-center "$@"' >gnome-control-center
   chmod 755 gnome-control-center
   ```
2. Test it by running the program:

   ```
   ./gnome-control-center
   ```
3. If it worked, then logout and log back in to add ~/bin to your PATH.

Gnome-control-center should now work for you.

### Optional

A logical follow-up question might be, *"How do I get GNOME control center to show up in my menus?"* One answer is to copy /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications/ and remove the line that says `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;`. I'd recommend also changing `Name=Settings` to `Name=GNOME Settings`, just so it's more obvious in your menu which program it is.

Here's my ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop file, which you can copy directly:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNOME Settings
Icon=preferences-system
Exec=gnome-control-center --overview
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;System;
Keywords=Preferences;Settings;
```